# Deploying Azure Web Role Failing. value cannot be null

Tags: azure-web-roles, hotfix

I have a number of web applications live in azure, all web roles.

All have been published many times before, but when I try to publish any of them now, I am getting a failure.  The feedback is:

> Value cannot be null, Parameter name: s.

I think this may be related to Microsoft's update KB3211320, as everything was OK before this update.  Unfortunately, it cannot be uninstalled and system restore is failing.

Azure WebRole Deployment Failure:

[image]

Comment: Same error here. However KB3211320 was installed last month and deployed fine with it just yesterday.. could be server side..

Comment: Same here, deployment worked yesterday around 8AM UTC and did not at 22PM UTC. Worth noting : not a single change in the Azure projects or the web project. Do you use application insight ?

Comment: Worth noting that creating the package and manually updating the cloud service works. Not a solution, but a workaround until they fix it. I'll try creating a support ticket and see what they say about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened a ticked with Microsoft, and they replied with this:

> It has already been identified as backend issue and now I am working
>   with Product Team with highest severity to fix it.

They provided a workaround, too:

> As a temporary workaround, you can disable Diagnostic first and
>   redeploy again.

I personally am not ok with disabling diagnostics and will publish with packages until it is resolved, but you might find it useful if you can't access the portal with enough rights to do a manual update.

**Edit:** They rolled back the changes, now it works as before.

Comment: Thanks for the input everybody.  Microsoft confirmed it was a backend issue and it was rectified by them.